# Responsiveslides - how to add and remove id on active slide

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-slides

I want to assign an id on an active slide image and remove it when the active image changes.

```
if ($('.rslides1_on').css('opacity') == '1') {
    $(".rslides1_on img").attr("id", "gxid");
} else if ($('.rslides1_on').css('opacity') == '0') {
    $(".rslides1_on img").removeAttr('id');
}
```

But this code is always assigning  the id on the first slide.

Comment: what sets $('.rslides1_on') opacity to 0 and does it actually set it to 0? Btw manipulating element ids isn't a common way and does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Thank you.. I will look into it more for other way..

Comment: If you could tell us bit more on what you're trying to achieve...